# Enable users to "hotfix" source data while waiting for upstream source data to change

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, data-management, azure-synapse, dbt

For a few SaaS tools our company uses, a 3rd party administrates the tools and provides us with daily feeds, which we load into our data warehouse.

Occasionally, a record in one of the feeds will have an error that needs to be fixed ASAP for downstream reporting. However, the SLA for the 3rd party to correct the record(s) in the source SaaS system can take up to two weeks. The 'error' doesn't break anything it is just that a record is closed when it should have stayed open, or a field has the wrong value.

The process is as follows:

1. BI team A, downstream of us in the data warehouse team, notices the discrepancy.
2. BI team A corrects the record in their database, which other teams consume from
3. BI team B, which receives data from the data warehouse and BI team A, raises an alarm because they see a discrepancy between our output and that which they receive from team A.
4. We (data warehouse team) have to correct the source data
5. The upstream 3rd party eventually corrects the records

Does anyone have a best practice for this scenario? What is an approach that would:

A. enable the BI team A to correct records ASAP without impacting the data warehouse team, and
B. be rollback-able once the upstream 3rd party corrects the source data?

One idea I had was to use a source-controlled csv file (like a [`dbt` `seed`](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/building-a-dbt-project/seeds) table) were it not that records usually contain PII and therefore can't version controlled.

Comment: You've tagged Snowflake and Azure Synapse.  Which of those is the solution you are loading data into?  There is a pretty good solution using Snowflake's VALIDATE() function, if that's your target database.

Comment: We’re using Synapse. I tagged Snowflake so I could get the great user support community like yourself lol.

Comment: awwww...shucks. Can't help you with Synapse, though.

Comment: I’m def going to look into `VALIDATE` though!

Comment: Hi - at what point in your pipeline do you identify the error - when it is in a staging table or after it has been loaded into your DW? What sort of errors are you seeing: just incorrect data in a field (but with no other impact) or errors that are causing whole fact/dimension records to be created incorrectly? Are you having to "back out" incorrect data from your DW or just correct incorrect source records and then load them?

Comment: @NickW just updated my question to answer yours. thanks for hleping!

Answer (score 1):

how I would approach this:

1. Ensure that you have controls on your DW to catch any errors. Having a consumer of your data (BI Team A) telling you that your data is wrong is not a good place to be in!
2. Have 1 team responsible for fixing the data and in 1 place - this ensures you have control, consistency and auditing. As the data starts in the DW and then moves downstream to other systems, the DW is the place to fix it.
3. Build a standard process for fixing data that involves as little manual intervention as possible and which has been developed and tested in advance. When you encounter an error, and are under pressure from your customers to fix it, the last thing you want is to be trying to work out how to resolve the error and then developing/running untested code
4. At a high-level, your standard process should be a copy of the Production process e.g. a copy of the staging table (where you can insert the corrected versions of the incorrect records) and a copy of the loading process but pointed at this copied staging table . Depending on your Production logic you may need to amend the copy to delete/insert or update the incorrect records in your DW. Depending on your toolset, you might be able to achieve this with a separate config file rather than copying tables/logic.
5. Auditing. You should always be able to trace the fact that records have been amended, which records have been affected and what the changes were

Obviously you need to ensure that the changes you make to the DW cascade down to any consuming systems - either in the regular update process (if your consumers can wait until then) or as a one-off process. Similarly, you need to ensure that when the amended record is finally received from the 3rd Party that it updates your DW correctly and that you've audited the fact that an error has been corrected - presumably you'd want to be able to report on any errors not fixed by the 3rd party within their SLA?